# Use JQuery to choose dom and chang it

Tags: jquery, html

my html code are:

```
<h2>123</h2>
<p>123</p>
<h3>123<h3>
<p>123</p>
<h2>456</h2>
<p>123</p>
<h3>123<h3>
<p>123</p>
<h2>456</h2>
<p>123</p>
<h3>123<h3>
<p>123</p>
```

I want them to be like this:

```
<div>
    <h2>123</h2>
    <p>123</p>
    <h3>123<h3>
    <p>123</p>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>456</h2>
    <p>123</p>
    <h3>123<h3>
    <p>123</p>
</div>
```

and the page not change,only tag change

**How to do this use Jquery?**

Answer (score 5):

You can use [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to partition your elements, and [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to create the surrounding `<div>` elements:

```
$("h2").each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil("h2").andSelf().wrapAll("<div></div>");
});
```